# How to get Date and Time from different textbox in c# and save to database?

Tags: c#

I have 2 text box name txtdate and TextBoxTime and 1 Dropdown list with name ddlampm now I need to insert date and time with format "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM AM/PM" into sqlserver how can I do that?

Comment: and I have only one field in database to add date and time together

Comment: But your doubt is regarding the code needed to perform the insert on the database, or only on the insert clause itself? What have you tried? Place your code.

Comment: You only tagged your question with `C#`. But what is the UI? .net, asp.net, winforms, wcf?

Comment: What specifically are you asking?  Where specifically are you stuck?  You've outlined some general descriptions of what you want to do, but have you tried anything and actually encountered a problem?  Start with any one piece of the overall functionality you want, such as getting the values from your inputs or using values to build your `DateTime`, or inserting into the database.  Which specific piece doesn't work as expected when you try?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new DateTime object using the constructor, and pass in the relevant values from both inputs.  Then you can use a parameterized query to insert the data into your database.  That will take care of date formatting.  Do not insert by building a string.